# Oracle SQL PLSQL large number field strange behavior

Tags: oracle, plsql, numbers

Have existing table called temptable, column largenumber is a NUMBER field, with no precision set:

```
largenumber NUMBER;
```

Query:

```
select largenumber from temptable;
```

It returns:

```
-51524845525550100000000000000000000
```

But If I do

```
column largenumber format 999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

And then

```
select largenumber from temptable;
```

It returns:

```
-51524845525550:100000000000000000000
```

Why is there a colon?

To test, I took the number, remove the colon, and insert it to another table temptable2, and did the same column largenumber format, the select returns the number without the colon:

```
select largenumber from temptable2;
```

It returns:

```
-51524845525550100000000000000000000
```

So the colon is not present here.

So what could possibly be in the original number field to cause that colon?

In the original row, If I do a select and try to do any TO_CHAR, REPLACE, CAST, or concatenate to text, it would give me number conversion error.

For example, trying to generate a csv:

```
select '"' || largenumber || '",'
FROM temptable;
```

would result in:

> ```
> ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a valid number
> ```

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my 11g, using SQL*Plus. There's no colon in output.

Comment: Try `select dump(largenumber) from {your_first_table}` and show us what it comes back with. The `dump` function works on all expressions (of any data type) and it shows exactly what is stored on disk, in raw form. That may give us some clues.

Comment: I picked another # as example.
Value when doing simple select
-514548495355000000000000000000000000

Dump(largenumber):
Typ=2 Len=8: 45,50,56,53,52,48,46,48

setting column itembalance format 999999999999999999999999999999999999999:
value returned:
51454849535553:100000000000000000000

Comment: @Littlefoot . That is what I experienced. If I were to manually insert the value to another table, it would not have the same behavior.

Comment: dump(-514548495355000000000000000000000000) on Windows/Linux gives me Typ=2 Len=8: 45,50,56,53,52,48,46,102. What platform are you on?

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald - The internal representation of numbers is platform-independent, isn't it?

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald From Linux platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment (in response to a question from me), you shared that `dump(largenumber)` on the offending value returns

```
Typ=2 Len=8: 45,50,56,53,52,48,46,48
```

From the outset, that means that the data stored on disk is invalid (it is not a valid representation of a value of `number` data type). `Typ=2` is correct, that is for data type `number`. The length (8 bytes) is correct (we can all count to eight to see that).

What is wrong is the bytes themselves. And, we only need to inspect the first and the last byte to see that.

The first byte is 45. It encodes the sign and the exponent of your number. The first bit (1 or 0) represents the sign: 1 for positive, 0 for negative. 45 is less than 128, so the first bit in the first byte is 0; so the number is negative. (So far this matches what you know about the *intended* value.)

But, for negative numbers, the last byte is **always** the magic value 102. **Always**. In another comment under your original question, Connor McDonald asks about your platform - but this is platform-independent, it is how Oracle encodes numbers for permanent storage on any platform. So, we already know that the `dump` value you got tells us the value is invalid.

In fact, Connor, in the same comment, gave the correct representation of that number (according to Oracle's scheme for internal representation of numbers). Indeed, just the last byte is wrong: your `dump` shows 48, but it should be 102.

How can you fix this? If it's a one-off, just use an `update` statement to replace the value with the correct one and move on. If your table has a primary key, let's call it `id`, then find the `id` for this row, and then

```
update {your_table} set largenumber = -50...... where id = {that_id};
```

Question is, how many such corrupt values might you have in your table? If it's just one, you can shrug it off; but if it's many (or even "a handful") you may want to figure out how they got there in the first place.

In most cases, the database will reject invalid values; you can't simply insert `'abc'` in a `number` column, for example. But **there are ways** to get bad data in; even intentionally, and in a repeatable way. So, you would have to investigate how the bad values were inserted (what process was used for insertion).

For a trivial way to insert bad data in a `number` column, in a repeatable manner, you can see this thread on the Oracle developers forum: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3903746/detecting-invalid-values-in-the-db

Please be advised that I had just started learning Oracle at that time (I was less than two months in), so I may have said some stupid things in that thread; but the method to insert bad data is described there in full detail, and it was tested. That shows just one possible (and plausible!) way to insert invalid stuff in a table; how it happened in your specific case, you will have to investigate yourself.